# Inputting (fitting) a model equation

Tags: matlab, statistics, data-fitting, model-fitting, state-space

I have the following model I want to fit using the `fittype` function in MATLAB:

[image: model]

`x`, which is the last (highlighted) line, is the final model.

`A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` are the parameters I'm interested in. I know **k** is the independent variable, but the `x` parts are really throwing me off. So I dont know how to input this model as an argument in `fittype`. Everything I've tried so far seems really off so I'm sure this is where I'm stuck.

I'd appreciate any help.